# How to return HttpStatus 204 in Mono webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

It's possible return a `Mono<Object>` with statusCode `204` (NO_CONTENT)?

I need that, for example postman show something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If using a Controller, this should do (replace path, method, etc as needed):

```
   @GetMapping(value = "/no-content")
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
   @ResponseBody
   public Mono<Object> noContentMethod()
   {
      // ... processing here ...
      return Mono.empty();
   }
```

Comment: Indeed, though I think `Mono<Void>` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: The question asked to "... return a `Mono<Object>`" :-)

Comment: Yeah I know :) I suspect the OP didn't know about the Void type, and I think telling him/her about it would've been appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>>` instead of `Mono<Object>`.
Response entity can be used to provide the proper response codes

For this case

`return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build());`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `ServerResponse`.

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> create(MyEntity entity) {
    return just(save(entity))
            .map(created(fromCurrentRequestUri()
                                 .pathSegment("{id}")
                                 .build()
                                 .expand(entity.getId())
                                 .toUri()).build());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not compatible return a `Mono<Object>` with a http status 204. If you want a 204 you should return `Mono<Void>` like this sample using routerFunctions:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> checkWithout(final ServerRequest request) {
    return noContent()
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use **ResponseEntity** , like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/elb", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity elbHealthCheck() {
    return HealthStatus.HEALTHY.equals(healthService.getHealthStatus())
            ? ResponseEntity.ok().build()
            : ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
}
```

Off course in your case, you just need to replace that HttpStatus code. Cheers!